# Disable warnings and notices for part of a page php

Tags: php, logging, error-handling, error-reporting, phpdocx

We are trying to add the PHP Library PHPDocx for dynamically making Microsoft word docs through our php application. However, their code throughs several warnings and notices that are blowing up our error log. We have our error reporting set to `E_STRICT` for the site, and want to change the error reporting and logging to `E_ERROR` just for these files. Unfortunately, our custom templating system (which sets the error reporting), is loaded prior to any requires or references to the PHPDocx library.

I have tried using `error_reporting(E_ERROR)` and `ini_set('display_errors', 0)`, but I am still getting the warnings and notices written into our error log. I don't know if its because all of our setup code is run first, but what I would like to do do is only write fatal errors from the PHPDocx files, but keep `E_STRICT` on the rest of the site.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think a well-coded script should not throw any error, warning or notice, but many people prefer to set error_reporting to ignore notices. This is not a good practice, as a notice sometimes gives a hint for a serious bug in the design of a script.

Comment: I would agree Jocelyn, but I am not familiar enough with what PHPDocx does to edit their code to stop throwing notices and warnings. I am not sure what dependencies there are between files, and what I might break by changing things. That is why I want to ignore notices and errors from their stuff only.

Comment: I am curious as to what errors it is throwing...  considering there are paid versions of this, you would think they would be handling them internally.

Comment: @Dave Primarily they are undefined index errors. For example, they call a chart building function in the constructor for their document object even though we didn't pass any information for a chart (because we don't want one). There are about 500 or so undefined indexes that get thrown just through the plain createDocx function. There are some undefined variable errors that break certain functions as well. Unfortunately, this is a poorly built library with almost no documentation beyond autocomments inserted by an IDE, but we are stuck with it at the moment.

Comment: `Unfortunately, this is a poorly built library with almost no documentation` - yuck...  is this the "free" version?  I am resistant to siggesting it, but would polying up the price for a pro version get you a more stable release without the issues?  Looking for quickest resolution for you at this point.

Comment: This is the Pro + version that they charge $150 bucks for. They have a commercial version for $400, but given this quality, I am not interested in purchasing that one.

Comment: I suspect that the included files are setting error levels that are overriding yours.  if you are using an ide, search the solution for error_reporting and display_errors and see if you get any hits, or move your error level setting to after their includes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if they are a small number of occurances, you could specifically suppress them with the `@` symbol before whatever function.  for example;

```
echo @$myunsetvariable;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there stuff throws about 500 undefined index warnings that I know of so far. There are approximately 7000 files in their library, and it would be nearly impossible to go through each function and add the error suppressor. I certainly wouldn't say they have developed a sustainable and solid solution, but it does produce the result we are looking for (minus the notices/warnings).

Comment: your comment about the includes files worked. I changed the error reporting after all of the includes and now I don't get all the undefined index errors. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```